# Node.js how to get http message (request, response) from net server (tcp server)?

Tags: node.js, html, sockets, browser, tcp

I have the following code :

```
var net = require('net');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
path = path.join(__dirname, 'index.html');

var fileAsAstream = fs.createReadStream(path);
var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socket.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nContent-Length: 10\r\n\r\n");
  fileAsAstream.pipe(socket);
  console.log("server is up. port 8081");
});

server.listen(8081);
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

(1) Why does chrome make two connections to the server when I try http://localhost:8081 ?  How can I make it work with one connection? And how I can format the html file in the browser during this tcp server.
or if there is something that can help me.

(2) It just reads the html file one time when I try to make two connections at telnet.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 10
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
Connection to host lost.
```

Comment: one of the requests is probably for `favicon.ico` that's something chrome does automaticly and i don't think there's anything you can do about it